# Image is the wrong size in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to use Kivy to display a background image, so I want the root widget to be the same size as the image. Currently, when I load the image from the kv file it appears as a small thumbnail in the bottom-left corner. The app window appears to be about the correct (full-scale) size, but hard to tell. Code below, any thoughts?

.kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.8.0

<BarBot_splash>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: image.size

        Image:
            id: image
            source: 'MainMenu.png'
```

.py file:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class BarBot_splash(Widget):
    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.x < self.width/3:
            #we touched the menu button
            pass
        elif touch.x > self.width/3*2:
            #we touched the custom button
            pass
        else:
            return False

class BarBot(App):
    def build(self):
        return BarBot_splash()

if __name__=='__main__':
    BarBot().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In main.py:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class BarBot_splash(BoxLayout): # subclass BoxLayout.. now it's inherently a Boxlayout
```

**kv:**

```
#:kivy 1.8.0

<BarBot_splash>: # I'm a BoxLayout...
    Image:
        id: image
        source: 'MainMenu.png'
```

That should do the trick. The `BoxLayout` should take up the window. It's one child, the `Image`, should in turn take up the full size of the `BoxLayout`. Why? Well, someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I think it's because the `size_hint` property of the `BoxLayout` and the `Image` both default to `(1, 1)`, which translates to: "Take up as much space in your parent as you can" or (100% width, 100% height). Though it may not be possible for a child to take up all of it's parents area if there are also other children in the parent, like if you had a few `Image`s in the `BoxLayout`, or more than one `BoxLayout` in your app etc.. Setting a size_hint to `(.5, .3)` would mean take up (50% the width, 30% the height) of your parent/container, or available space.

Answer (score 2):

BarBot_splash is just a widget, so it doesn't apply any position or size to its children, therefore the boxlayout (and thus its child image) have only the default position of (0, 0) and size of (100, 100).

Change BarBot_splash to a BoxLayout or other resizing layout and this will propagate correctly. You also don't need the `size: image.size` line, this does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously very old question but I'm new to Kivy and just had to work through a very similar problem and there was very little help on the topic, so this is for future people like me:

I had the same problem but the image was also in a scatter widget. Solution is really simple, just frustrating to find. Hierarchy has to be as follows:

```
BoxLayout:
    Scatter:
        size: image.size
        Image:
            id: image
            size: root.size
```